# how to Socket io with swift language

Tags: swift, socket.io

Here is my socket io swift language code

and main.js file code also here

I have not properly idea why is not with socket io server.

```
  let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
  self.socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/")
  establishSocketConnection()

  func establishSocketConnection() {

    self.socket.connect()
    self.socket.on("connection") { ( dataArray, ack) -> Void in
        print("connected to external server")

    }
  }

  func cloesSocketConnection() {
    self.socket.disconnect()
  }
```

log:

```
2019-03-27 23:38:36.228040+0530 scoket[1693:38288] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
2019-03-27 23:38:36.228241+0530 scoket[1693:38288] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
2019-03-27 23:38:36.228353+0530 scoket[1693:38288] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
2019-03-27 23:38:36.228437+0530 scoket[1693:38288] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
2019-03-27 23:38:36.229083+0530 scoket[1693:38288] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connection
2019-03-27 23:38:36.229115+0530 scoket[1693:38343] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://localhost:3000
2019-03-27 23:38:36.229203+0530 scoket[1693:38343] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2019-03-27 23:38:36.229239+0530 scoket[1693:38288] LOG SocketManager: Manager is being released
2019-03-27 23:38:36.232066+0530 scoket[1693:38343] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
2019-03-27 23:38:36.331457+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2019-03-27 23:38:36.331618+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 96:0{"sid":"yaMqmjKGkhok6TuqAAAC","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}2:40
2019-03-27 23:38:36.331884+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"yaMqmjKGkhok6TuqAAAC","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
2019-03-27 23:38:36.341490+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 40
2019-03-27 23:38:36.341726+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false
2019-03-27 23:38:36.342051+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
2019-03-27 23:38:36.342505+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
2019-03-27 23:38:36.342910+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
2019-03-27 23:38:36.343202+0530 scoket[1693:38346] LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being released
```

Comment: What does 'how to Socket io with swift language' mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the latest swift 4.2 code 
Connect with socket io server and get data in xcode

```
    func ConnectToSocket() {

      manager  = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

    socketIOClient = manager.defaultSocket

    socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print(data)
        print("socket connected")

        self.socketIOClient.emit("GetData", "dad")

    }

    socketIOClient.on("newChatMessage") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in

        print(dataArray)
    }

    socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: .error) { (data, eck) in
        print(data)
        print("socket error")
    }

    socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { (data, eck) in
        print(data)
        print("socket disconnect")
    }

    socketIOClient.on(clientEvent: SocketClientEvent.reconnect) { (data, eck) in
        print(data)
        print("socket reconnect")
    }

    socketIOClient.connect()

}
```

Comment: How to pass token to socket connection?

Answer (score 0):

your socket property it isn't true
your connection method must be like this:

```
func establishSocketConnection() {
  let socket = manager.defaultSocket
      self.socket.on("connection") { ( dataArray, ack) -> Void in
    print("connected to external server")

     }
}
```

and every time you want to create handler in socket (like socket.on or socket.emit) 
you must create socket variable again.

hope to this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this **SocketIOManger** for communicate with socket and make changes according to your need.
    class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

```
 static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()
 var manager : SocketManager?
 var socket : SocketIOClient?

 override init() {
     super.init()
 }

 /**
  Create socket connection.
  - parameter completionHandler : Called when complition will occure.
  - parameter connected : True when socket connected.
  - returns: nil
  */
 func createSocketConnection (completionHandler: @escaping (_ connected: Bool) -> Void) {
     let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: ConstantsBroadcast.Access_Token)!
     manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: ConstantsBroadcast.socketBaseUrl)!
        ,config: [.log(true),  .connectParams(["token": token]) ])

     socket = manager?.defaultSocket

     socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect) { data, ack in
         print("socket connected.")
         completionHandler(true)
     }
     socket?.connect()
 }

 /**
  Disconnect socket.
  */
 func closeConnection() {
     socket?.disconnect()
 }

 /**
  Add new user to socket.
  - parameter username: current user name.
  - parameter userid: current user id.
  - parameter image: current user profile image url.
  - returns: nil
  */
 func addUserToServer(username: String, userid: String, image: String) { 
     let dict = ["username" : username, "userId": userid, "profileImage":image] as [String : Any]
     self.socket?.emit("adduser", dict) //adduser

 }

 /**
  Add handler for total connected user.
  - parameter completionHandler : Called when complition will occure.
  - parameter userCount : Total number of  connected users.
  - returns: nil
  */
 func userConnectionHandlers(completionHandler: @escaping (_ userCount: String) -> Void) {
     socket?.on("updateconnecteduser") { data,ack in //updateconnecteduser
         debugPrint("connected user : ",data)
         if let snippet = data[0] as? NSDictionary {
             completionHandler("\(String(describing: snippet.value(forKey: "viewers")!))")
         }
     }
 }

 /**
  Send new message.
  - parameter message: user text message.
  - returns: nil
  */
 func sendMessage(message :String){
     if socket?.status == .connected {
         self.socket?.emit("sendchat", ["message": message]) //sendchat
     }
     else{
         print("socket not connected")
     }
 }

 /**
  Add handler for get new messages.
  - parameter completionHandler : Called when complition will occure.
  - parameter messageInfo : New message data.
  - returns: nil
  */
 func newMessageHandlers(completionHandler: @escaping (_ messageInfo: ChatItemModel) -> Void) {
     socket?.on("updatechat") { data,ack in //updatechat
         print(data)
         var msgData = ChatItemModel()
         if let chatData = data[0] as? NSDictionary {
             if let mId = chatData.value(forKey: "chatCommentId") as? String{
                 msgData.ChatCommentId = mId
             }
             if let userId = chatData.value(forKey: "userId") as? String {
                 msgData.UserID = userId
             }
             if let username = chatData.value(forKey: "username") as? String{
                 msgData.UserName = username
             }
             if let image = chatData.value(forKey: "profileImage") as? String{
                 msgData.ProfileImage = image
             }
             if let message = chatData.value(forKey: "message") as? String{
                 msgData.Message = message
             }
             if let createdAt = chatData.value(forKey: "createdAt") as? String{
                 msgData.CreatedAT = createdAt
             }

             completionHandler(msgData)
         }
     }
 }



 /**
  Block user.
  - parameter userId: user id.
  - returns: nil
  */
 func blockUser(userId : String){
     if socket?.status == .connected {
         self.socket?.emit("blockuser", ["userId" : userId]) //blockuser
         print("blockuser emmited : ", userId)
     }
     else{
         print("socket not connected")
     }
 }

 /**
  Add handler for block user.
  - parameter completionHandler : Called when complition will occure.
  - parameter userId : Blocked user id.
  - returns: nil
  */
 func blockUserHandler(completionHandler: @escaping (_ status : Int, _ userId: String) -> Void) {
     socket?.on("updateblockeduser") { data,ack in //updateblockeduser
         print("blcked userId  : ",data)

         if let blockedItem = data[0] as? NSDictionary {
             if let status = blockedItem.value(forKey: "status") as? Int{
                 if let userId = blockedItem.value(forKey: "userId") as? String{
                     completionHandler(status, userId)

                 }
             }

         }

     }
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I m passing token to socket but it not works, what should i do?